# Disable lack of PHP executable path in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I use Windows10 home and I'm having this notification in Visual Studio code:

> Cannot validate since no PHP executable is set. Use the setting
>   'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable.

I don't want to have it, so I went to preferences > settings.JSON and added:

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": null
}
```

I saved, closed the program, and then opened a PHP file but I still get the notification.

How could I totally remove that notification?

The reason I want to remove it is because I usually don't do PHP development on windows, rather, on Linux and I want to keep my Windows environment minimal without installing PHP on it.

Edit: I don't have any extensions on VSCODE besides "ESLint" for JavaScript.